# Access form must be opened twice before combobox values will appear

Tags: ms-access

I have a checklist that is used to perform QC audits.  When a reviewer answers a question that requires an exception, a pop-up form will open with the correct exception detail already populated.  They then have to provide some further information, which I have set-up in the format of a combobox for a field named 'Condition_Detail.'  Some exceptions have only one condition that would be an option in the drop-down whereas others have multiple possible conditions, which is why I don't have that field automatically populated as well.  I have a table of possible exceptions and conditions that I have used to create the combobox query.  When the database was created, the field the 'Condition_Detail' combobox is dependent on was labeled 'Exception Detail' with a space and in my new table it is called 'Exception_Detail.' I did this because the old data and tables will eventually become irrelevant and I know that it is easier to write code with underscores instead of spaces.  I include this information because I had to create a relationship between those two fields in the combobox query so that the database would know they are the same.  When I test the database, the form opens as expected with the exceptions already populated (NOT in combobox format - the data appears as text on the form).  The issue is that when I select the combobox, it is blank.  If I answer the exact same question the same way to trigger the same exception to open in a new record, the combobox does have the correct data in it.  I have tried to requery the field both when the form loads and after it updates.  It still won't show the combobox values unless I trigger that the form open twice with the same detail populated.  An additional piece of information that likely doesn't affect the problem is that the combobox is set-up as three columns so that I can populate two additional fields when the condition detail has been updated.  I used the code below to populate that, which works perfectly when I can get the condition detail to appear in the combobox:

```
Private Sub Condition_Details_Change()
Me.Responsible_Position.Value = Me.Condition_Details.Column(2)
Me.Severity_Description.Value = Me.Condition_Details.Column(3)
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: *"combobox is set-up as three columns"*  Since the column numbering starts at zero, those 3 columns would be referenced as `Column(0)`, `Column(1)` and `Column(2)`.  But there is no `Column(3)`, so I can't understand how you see data from it.  Access won't complain; it will just give you Null for `Column(3)`.

Comment: Thank you!  I got that part figured out, and determined the rest was a user error on my part.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  The relationship I created within the combo box query was unnecessary.  The query was searching for values in the table that stored the actual responses/conditions instead of the table that stored the available response options.  Because of this, once I had answered the question it knew what to look for, but in the wrong place.  Setting up the combo box the usual way with the look-up control value in the form referenced as follows was sufficient to get the combo box to work properly.

```
Field: Exception_Text
Table: tblPreCloseExceptionDescEnc
Criteria: [Forms]![frmEncompassExceptions].[Form]![Exception Text]
```